# Sql Server 2005 Installation without Tools?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am installing SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.

But when the installation has finished installing, tools like Management Studio, Business Intelligence and Analysis Services are displayed.

Comment: i have only one dvd.and the installtion package does not ask for it or give any option

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, those tools are on CD 2

---

Check out this [post](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/Coffeehouse/139463-Installing-SQL-Server-2005-Standard/):

> There should be two items list under
>   the Install when you first insert the
>   DVD. It should look something like
>   this:
>
> **Server components, tools, Books Online, and samples**
>
> **Run the SQL Native Client Installation Wizard**
>
> You have installed the "Run the SQL
>   Native Client Installation Wizard",
>   next you need to install the "Server
>   components, tools, Books Online, and
>   samples". This is where you will get
>   SQL Server and the Server Management
>   Studio.

Comment: i have only one dvd.and the installtion package does not ask for it or give any option

Answer (score 0):

You're *missing* the tools? Or you have them? Not clear. I believe Express installs w/out the tools. Are you sure you're installing Standard?